# Eclipse Oxygen - The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse Oxygen and tried to open an existing project into the workbench but I get this error:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try
>   building this project

I tried right clicking on the project - went to Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries - Add Library - JRE System Library and selected Workbench default JRE (jre1.8.0_60).

I then cleaned and rebuilt the project but it then causes more errors to come up like:

```
ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type
Activity cannot be resolved to a variable
AdapterView cannot be resolved to a type
ArrayAdapter cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Could you switch to Android Studio instead ? Because Eclipse is deprecated now.

Answer (score 19):

Here is what made the error disappear for me:

Close eclipse, open up a terminal window and run:

```
$ mvn clean eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: the eclipse maven plugin is obsolete... you can use it to clean *some* eclipse generated files but don't use the configuration generator because it clashes with m2e

Comment: Restart eclipse worked for me...

Comment: This worked for me for resolving VS Code java language server problem.

Answer (score 16):

Are you using Maven? If so,

1. Right-click on the project, Build Path and go to Configure Build Path
2. Click the libraries tab. If Maven dependencies are not in the list, you need to add it.
3. Close the dialog.

To add it:
Right-click on the project, Maven → Disable Maven Nature
Right-click on the project, Configure → Convert to Maven Project.

And then clean

**Edit 1:**

If that doesn't resolve the issue try right-clicking on your project and select properties. Select Java Build Path → Library tab. Look for a JVM. If it's not there, click to add Library and add the default JVM. If VM is there, click edit and select the default JVM. Hopefully, that works.

**Edit 2:**

You can also try going into the folder where you have all your projects and delete the `.metadata` for eclipse (be aware that you'll have to re-import all the projects afterwards! Also all the environment settings you've set would also have to be redone). After it was deleted just import the project again, and hopefully, it works.

Comment: No I am not using Maven. I already tried adding a JVM which a said in my question. When I do that it causes more errors

Comment: You can also try going into the folder where you have all your projects and delete the .metadata for Eclipse (be aware that you'll have to re-import all the projects afterwards! Also all the environment settings you've set would also have to be redone). After it was deleted just import the project again, and hopefully it works.

Comment: "To add it: Right-click on the project, Maven → Disable Maven Nature Right-click on the project, Configure → Convert to Maven Project." It fix my problem, but what is these step doing actually?

Comment: Edit 1 Worked for me (in Eclipse 2020-12). Apparently the JRE library is not always updated when the build path properties are changed. My JRE got stuck on JAVA-7 (because my bundles need to work for that), but somehow the compiler compliance levels did not change the selected JRE in the library

Comment: Same as @keesp the Edit 1 worked for me. If Maven Build Path doesn't fix the problem try to check the properties of the project and change the Java Build Path -> Library and try to use the same as Maven Build Path.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse, Right click Project -> `Maven` -> `Update Project`. It fixed errors in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Eclipse Oxygen, migrated from Mars. I faced the same error. I deleted `.metadata`, `.recommenders` folders and added projects from archive and issue is solved. I also use Android Studio but i like Eclipse much more.

Comment: Eclipse for Android is not supported now. You can't use Api 26+ and support libraries and some other stuff like MVVM, Room, etc. You should migrate to Android Studio. I resisted that for awhile but it became impossible to work without new libraries. You can use AS like Eclipse with workspace if you add projects as modules. I Keep 10+ separate projects in one project using modules and it gets quite easy to check out if i need some snippets from another project.

Answer (score 0):

At my system the Java Runtime JAR file **jrt-fs.jar** was not found because it was in the wrong directory. This file should be located in the "lib" subfolder. If you installed Java at "C:\Temp\java" the file should be here at C:\Temp\java\lib\jrt-fs.jar .

These are the steps to make **jrt-fs.jar** available to Eclipse:

1. Window / Preferences -> the "Preferences" Window opens
2. Select in the left menu: Java / Installed JREs
3. Press the [Add...] Button -> A window opens
4. Select "Standard VM" - The window "JRE Definition" opens.
5. Enter your path information:
6. JRE home = "C:\Temp\java"
7. JRE name = "MyJRE"
8. Select [Add External JARs...] to link the jrt-fs.jar
9. JRE system libaries: "C:\Temp\java\lib\jrt-fs.jar"

It worked for me with OpenJDK12 and Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13.0).
Eclipse reported me this error:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem. I added the C:\Users\Office 2\android-sdks\platforms\android-19\android.jar to the Java Build Path's Library. And the project started to run again.
The problem occurred due to my carelessness. Yesterday night I was updating the Android SDK, and at the same time I tried to run the project,  while the SDK Manager was uncompressing the system image. The Project couldn't start and the error occurred.

I tried all the methods given by others. But nothing worked. It solved when I added the android.jar to the library.

I guessed it that android library is missing. not the Java, when I saw the errors only at the android methods and imports. But when I read the posts, I got confused and wasted some time trying wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and tried different solutions, I have reinstalled my JDK 11 and restarted the machine, after that the issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue when importing Spring Boot, jdk 11 (using
inside docker) project to Eclipse 2019 (2021), in Ubuntu, instead when
importing to Inteelij IDEA Community or NetBeans IDEs they do
not produce the same set of after-import errors as in Eclipse.
The Spring Boot is multimodule maven projects and two child
modules give such 2 "problems" in appropriate problems tab:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. 
Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build 
path then try building this project
```

Next 2 errors are produced in two classes of aforementioned
maven modules:

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is 
indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Manipulation with adding JDK 11 to submodules buildpath
just leads to the thousands of problems. Also it is
got when I use Eclipse-File-Maven-Update.
Moreover when I try to edit most of existing classes or add new ones
I got red underline that tells

```
Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default 
constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

. So almost no opportunity to use Eclipse
even at prebuild stage as docker-compose should run build and
run. Indeed I noted that such issue is produced just when project
also uses modules (module-info files introduced in java9).
When I import project on jdk 8 (even not installed on
system), or even on jdk11 without module-info files all
is fine in Eclipse after import.
Another difference is that of when I use problem old no module
project the Build Path is composed with jre environment 8 and
maven dependency items, but when using
"module-info" project the Build path contains -module path,
and -classpath. So I even do not know where to add jre 11,
indeed adding does not resolve issue, just make more errors.
So what is the resolution of the case??? What settings to do
in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I got this out of the blue in a workspace that was working properly before. This problem seems to indicate that the project configuration somehow got corrupted.

Restarting Eclipse didn't help, but in the same vein as the answers dealing with Maven, regenerating the Eclipse project config with:

```
./gradle eclipse
```

or

```
./gradlew eclipse
```

if you use the wrapper, solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps of how I resolved the issue in my system.

- Restarted eclipse
- Right click on pom.xml and hit maven clean
- Again right click on pom.xml and hit maven install

I get build success after maven install is completed.

Answer (score 0):

This Helped me

Steps:

1. How to resolve java build path problem in Eclipse
2. Right click the project - select build path - click configure build path
3. click the librarie tab
4. remove the jre (error jre) we need to jdk
5. click Add Library
6. select JRE system library
7. click installed jre
8. click add button : or select jdk in this window if not available the jdk click add button
9. select the jdk directory in the system
10. select jdk and apply close
11. building the project
12. check it the build path problem resolved

You Can check the link below video:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHjfJnpwcTQ