# Project cannot find classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I am programming a Java project to learn about JPA & JDBC. The project in eclipse is called `WSShop` & accesses another eclipse project called `JPAUtilities`, which contains a class called `JPAUtils` that uses an `EntityManager` class.

My problem is that although there are no problems in the `JPAUtilities` project that uses `EntityManager`, the `WSShop` project using `JPAUtilities` has a problem finding `EntityManager` & gives the error messages

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.persistence.EntityManager. Fix the build path then try building this project WSShop      Unknown Java Problem
The type javax.persistence.EntityManager cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files JPAUserDAO.java /WSShop/src/main/java/com/example/demo  line 35 Java Problem
```

Here are the settings of the project & the subproject:

[image: <code>WSShop</code> properties]
[image: <code>JPAUtilities</code> properties]

I added the `java.persistence` JAR to the `WSShop` project, but still do get the same error:

[image: Code in <code>WSShop</code> project with errors]

But `JPAUtilities` is used by `WSShop`, but `JPAUtilities` does not have any problems (closed `WSShop` here):

[image: <code>JPAUtilities</code> code with closed <code>WSShop</code> project]

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Included subproject of <code>WSShop</code>]

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:**
I checked the `pom.xml` & reduced the errors to three. Now, `EntityManager` is no more a problem. The POM file contains the following lines among others:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

There exists the `…\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.7.RELEASE` directory with a `spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE` executable Jar file. I changed the configuration of the project as follows

[image: WSShop's new Java Build Path]

… and the error & warnings are now

[image: New errors & warnings]

Comment: Did you add `JPAUtilities` as a dependency on the `Projects` tab of `WSShop`?

Comment: Yes, I did. See the latest update of the question.

Comment: Can this be because of inconsistencies in the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: If you are using Maven, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205880/eclipse-oxygen-the-project-was-not-built-since-its-build-path-is-incomplete?rq=1

Comment: That's a good link, but I still could not get rid of problems – this time, `SpringApplication` seems to be "inaccessible".

Comment: With the new `spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE-jar` added to the classpath, the errors changed.